# How to prevent AJAX generated content to be indexed by search engines?

Tags: ajax, seo

i am injecting some text into my pages but i need to prevent search engines from indexing it. I read that some engines are able to read this content now. How can one prevent them from doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Search engines cannot read Ajax content yet. The closest they come is Google supporting it if you use [their specifications](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html). But that does require you using their specification otherwise Google can't crawl Ajax content.

Comment: thanks John, so you are saying that i should be pretty safe right now?

Comment: You should be safe for the foreseeable future. I'm sure you're site will be due for a redesign by the time they can index that content.

Comment: gotcha, but if i wanted to be proactive is there a way for me to encode/scramble the text that would prevent them from reading it, and it would be still readable?

Comment: At that point, the only way to prevent a search engine spider from reading that content is to send it over SSL.